# Should I use repository for Realm(ios)

Tags: ios, swift, service, repository, realm

First of all I'm relatively new in ios and have no any experience using mobile dbs.

Wanted to integrate into my app Realm(swift) and wonder if it make sense to have service layer and repository separated or everything just include into the service.

Some example to have a good view.

```
class UserService {

    var userRepository: UserRepository!

    func findById(userId: String) -> User? {
        return userRepository.findById(userId: userId)
    }
}

class UserRepository {

    private let realm = try! Realm()

    func findById(userId: String) -> User? {
        return realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: userId)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding an abstraction layer over the top of database APIs is pretty common. A lot of other developers have wrapped Realm in their own classes in order to hide the API from their business logic code.

There's a couple of considerations in which to be aware:

1. You need to be carful not to accidentally hurt performance from this. Some users have gone so far as to copy data out of Realm objects into their own objects. This defeats the purpose of Realm's 'zero-copy' mechanism, and so the app now inherently performs worse than using Realm natively.
2. This is 'pre-emptive work'. You're doing a lot of work up front, *just in case* you might change your mind down the line. I converted Core Data to Realm in a rather large app a while ago, and it only took a few hours. Trying to architect a 'generic' database solution which you may never end up using sounds like it might not pay off.
3. You're increasing app complexity. This means more potential for bugs and more rigorous testing would be needed to make sure your API and the database API are in sync.

As long as the new database you'd be moving to consists of managing objects as well (ie Core Data), converting from one database to another isn't usually a lot of work. As such, I'd recommend avoiding unnecessary work until the time when it becomes necessary.

**Disclaimer:** I work for Realm, but this is my opinion as someone who's shipped personal apps using Core Data, raw SQLite and Realm in the past.

Comment: Hi Tim, I know that you've worked for the Realm team, for point one, what do you recommend for this scenario:
You have a Realm object that is deleted elsewhere but in parallel you are trying to access it and will crash because at one point it will no longer be in a Realm. I was just thinking of doing something similar as you described in point 1 but now that I read that it might not be worth it. I would like to use a generic repository with a realm and type dependency injection I guess.

Comment: Hi @Cyupa! If you've got two Realm `Object` instances pointing at the same object on disk, if you delete one instance of the object, the other will automatically become invalidated and you'll no longer be able to read data from it. It really depends on 'why' you want to keep the data around post-deletion, but it's still an acceptable compromise to make an in-memory copy.

Comment: Hi @TiM, a small detail: Should we keep one "Realm" around in the app or create on for each repository or extension method like this?
private let realm = try! Realm()

Comment: @ThreadPitt Hi Thread! Realm instances are cached internally. There’s no overhead saving if you hold onto an existing reference. If it’s more convenient for you, then sure! But make sure you don’t try and access the reference from other threads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extensions to add your fetching methods.
You add Object subclasses for each entity in your database and then add extensions to each for these methods when needed.
Example:

```
import RealmSwift

// Dog model
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var owner: Person? // Properties can be optional
}
```

The for your fetching methods:

```
extension Dog {
    class func fetch(with name: String) -> Dog? {
        return try! Realm().objects(Dog.self).filter("name == %@", name).first
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, please correct me if I'm wrong, assume you mean I don't need repository layer, if so when I'll decide to change to CoreData then I'll have to remove/change all extensions of all my models or ?

Comment: You can use extensions in CoreData too. You can follow this tutorial backwards: https://news.realm.io/news/migrating-from-core-data-to-realm

Comment: This is from CoreData no to, but in any case I got your idea...
I thought more about which way(pattern) is more convenient if in the future will need to change DB

Comment: that why I said "backwards" meaning from Realm to CoreData